# How to determine the Xcode version used to make a build, from the IPA file?

Tags: xcode, ipa

Is there a way to do this? Can't seem to find any answer on the web yet.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is a way to do this. 

Instructions:
1. Change extension of your file from *.ipa to *.zip.
2. Unzip it.
3. Open extracted folder, right click on Application file and then choose "Show Package Contents".
4. Find Info.plist file and open it.
5. Find value for key "DTXcodeBuild".

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you. Then I just looked up the value of DTXcodeBuild on the Xcode Wikipedia page after getting its value from Info.plist

Comment: I think you can use DTXcode from info.plist  <key>DTXcode</key>
 <string>0731</string> this means 7.3.1